# Read data from FTS table?

Tags: android, sqlite, fts4

In one of implementing feature set application have to perform frequent Search Query directly from sqlite data Base. I found [FTS](https://developer.android.com/training/search/search.html) could be better way to perform faster search. I created it but it's returning no data. I checked by opening db file, Virtual Table Created but no data there.

My question is, does Virtual Table required to insert data manually before to fetch any data. Any suggestion !!

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html#section_1_3) says:

> FTS tables are populated using INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE statements in the same way as ordinary SQLite tables are.